# Strange border on fixed postition elements in firefox 7.0.1

Tags: css, firefox, css-position

There is a strange border on my fixed header and footer elements in firefox..

Does anyone know how to get rid of this or is it a bug?

[image: Firefox error]

[image]

[image]

**HTML**
This is the html for the home page..

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!-- Consider adding an manifest.appcache: h5bp.com/d/Offline -->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]--><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Use the .htaccess and remove these lines to avoid edge case issues.
        More info: h5bp.com/b/378 -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>my Sitelocker!</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <base href="http://sitelocker.local/" />

    <!-- Mobile viewport optimized: j.mp/bplateviewport -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory: mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons -->

    <!-- CSS: implied media=all -->
    <!-- CSS concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource/css/grid.css"/>
    <!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource/css/ie6.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource/css/ie.css" /><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource/css/uniform.default.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yellowtail' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="resource/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" />
    <!-- end CSS-->

    <!-- More ideas for your <head> here: h5bp.com/d/head-Tips -->

    <!-- All JavaScript at the bottom, except for Modernizr / Respond.
    Modernizr enables HTML5 elements & feature detects; Respond is a polyfill for min/max-width CSS3 Media Queries
    For optimal performance, use a custom Modernizr build: www.modernizr.com/download/ -->
    <script src="resource/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<header id="masthead" class="clearfix">

    <div id="masthead-inner" class="container_12 clearfix">

        <div id="logo" class="grid_6">

            <img src="resource/img/logo.jpg"/>

        </div><!--/#logo-->


        <div id="tools" class="grid_6">
                <a href="#" id="add-site-modal">Add Site</a>

            <ul id="top_menu">
                <li>Welcome, <strong>lemonfreshdesign</strong>.</li>
                <li><a href="http://sitelocker.local/account/account_settings">Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://sitelocker.local/account/sign_out">Sign out</a></li>
            </ul><!--/#top_menu-->


        </div><!--/#tools-->

    </div><!--/#masthead-inner-->

</header><!--/#masthead-->

<div id="main" role="main" class="container_12 clearfix">

    <div id="main_inner">    

        <div id="ajaxLoadAni">
            <img src="resource/img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Ajax Loading Animation" />
            <span>Loading...</span>
        </div><!--/#ajaxLoadAni-->

        <div id="siteholder" class="column grid_12 clearfix">

        </div><!--/#siteholder-->

        <div id="delConfDialog" title="Confirm">
            <p>Are you sure?</p>
        </div><!--/#siteholder-->


        <div id="msgDialog">
            <p></p>
        </div><!--/#siteholder-->

        <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">

            <form action="http://sitelocker.local/usersites/insert_site" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="addsite_form"> <input id="account_id" type="hidden" value="1"/>
                <label for="site_title"><strong>Site Name:</strong></label> 
                <input id="site_title" type="text" maxLength="25" tabindex="1" name="site_title" /> 
                <label for="site_url"><strong>Site Address:</strong></label> 
                <input id="site_url" type="text" tabindex="2" name="site_url" /> 
                <label for="site_description"><strong>Site Description:</strong></label> 
                <input id="site_description" type="text" tabindex="3" name="site_description" /> 
                <label for="site_category"><strong>Site Category:</strong></label> 
                <input id="site_category" type="text" tabindex="4" name="site_category" /> 
                <input id="addsite_form_submit" type="submit" value="Add Site" name="submit" class="addsite_form_submit" tabindex="5" /> 
            </form>

        </div><!--/#myModal-->

    </div><!--/#main_inner -->

</div><!--/#main -->

<footer id="footer" class="clearfix">

    <div id="footer-container" class="container_12 clearfix">

        <div id="copyright" class="grid_4">

        &copy; my SiteLocker 2011 | All Rights Reserved

        </div><!--/#copyright -->

        <div id="benchmarking" class="grid_4">

        Page rendered in 0.0533 seconds

        </div><!--/#benchmarking -->

        <div id="category-select" class="grid_4">

            <form>
                <select style="opacity: 0;">
                    <option value="option1">Category</option>
                    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
                </select>

            </form>

        </div><!--/#category-select -->

    </div><!--/#footer-container -->

</footer><!--/#footer -->

<!-- JavaScript at the bottom for fast page loading -->

<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if offline -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="resource/js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<!-- scripts concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
<script defer src="resource/js/libs/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>

<script defer src="resource/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/template" id="readTemplate">

<div class="scroll-content-item dragbox clearfix" id="dragbox${site_id}">

    <h2 class="h2handle"><a href="${site_url}">${site_title}</a><span class="close"><a href="http://sitelocker.local/usersites/delete_site/${site_id}" id="${site_id}" class="deleteBtn"><img src="resource/img/closepanel.png"></a></span></h2>

    <div class="dragbox-content">

        <p><a class="sitelink" href="${site_url} ?>" title="${site_title}"><img src="http://immediatenet.com/t/l?Size=1024x768&URL=${site_url}" alt="${site_title}" title="${site_title}"/></a></p>

    </div>
    <div class="dragbox-footer">
    <p>in: ${site_category}</p> 
    </div>

</div> 
</script>
<script defer src="resource/js/script.js"></script>
<script>
    //display ajax loader animation
    $( '#ajaxLoadAni' ).fadeIn( 'slow' );
    $('a#viewqr').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div#qr').reveal({
            animation: 'fadeAndPop',                   //fade, fadeAndPop, none
            animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
            closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
        });
    });

</script>   
<!-- end scripts-->

<!-- Change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
<script>
    window._gaq = [['_setAccount','UAXXXXXXXX1'],['_trackPageview'],['_trackPageLoadTime']];
    Modernizr.load({
        load: ('https:' == location.protocol ? '//ssl' : '//www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'
    });

</script>


<!-- Prompt IE 6 users to install Chrome Frame. Remove this if you want to support IE 6.
    chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started -->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.3/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.attachEvent('onload',function(){CFInstall.check({mode:'overlay'})})</script>
<![endif]-->

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**
This is the main layout css file for the main page

```
/* 
 * HTML5 ✰ Boilerplate
 *
 * What follows is the result of much research on cross-browser styling. 
 * Credit left inline and big thanks to Nicolas Gallagher, Jonathan Neal,
 * Kroc Camen, and the H5BP dev community and team.
 *
 * Detailed information about this CSS: h5bp.com/css
 * 
 * ==|== normalize ==========================================================
 */


/* =============================================================================
   HTML5 display definitions
   ========================================================================== */

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section { display: block; }
audio, canvas, video { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; }
audio:not([controls]) { display: none; }
[hidden] { display: none; }

/* =============================================================================
   Base
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * 1. Correct text resizing oddly in IE6/7 when body font-size is set using em units
 * 2. Force vertical scrollbar in non-IE
 * 3. Prevent iOS text size adjust on device orientation change, without disabling user zoom: h5bp.com/g
 */

html { font-size: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }

body { margin: 0; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.231; }

body, button, input, select, textarea { font-family: sans-serif; color: #222; }

/* 
 * Remove text-shadow in selection highlight: h5bp.com/i
 * These selection declarations have to be separate
 * Also: hot pink! (or customize the background color to match your design)
 */

::-moz-selection { background: #fe57a1; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background: #fe57a1; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }


/* =============================================================================
   Links
   ========================================================================== */

a { color: #00e; }
a:visited { color: #551a8b; }
a:hover { color: #06e; }
a:focus { outline: thin dotted; }

/* Improve readability when focused and hovered in all browsers: h5bp.com/h */
a:hover, a:active { outline: 0; }


/* =============================================================================
   Typography
   ========================================================================== */

abbr[title] { border-bottom: 1px dotted; }

b, strong { font-weight: bold; }

blockquote { margin: 1em 40px; }

dfn { font-style: italic; }

hr { display: block; height: 1px; border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 1em 0; padding: 0; }

ins { background: #ff9; color: #000; text-decoration: none; }

mark { background: #ff0; color: #000; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; }

/* Redeclare monospace font family: h5bp.com/j */
pre, code, kbd, samp { font-family: monospace, monospace; _font-family: 'courier new', monospace; font-size: 1em; }

/* Improve readability of pre-formatted text in all browsers */
pre { white-space: pre; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }

q { quotes: none; }
q:before, q:after { content: ""; content: none; }

small { font-size: 85%; }

/* Position subscript and superscript content without affecting line-height: h5bp.com/k */
sub, sup { font-size: 75%; line-height: 0; position: relative; vertical-align: baseline; }
sup { top: -0.5em; }
sub { bottom: -0.25em; }


/* =============================================================================
   Lists
   ========================================================================== */

ul, ol { margin: 1em 0; padding: 0 0 0 40px; }
dd { margin: 0 0 0 40px; }
nav ul, nav ol { list-style: none; list-style-image: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }


/* =============================================================================
   Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * 1. Improve image quality when scaled in IE7: h5bp.com/d
 * 2. Remove the gap between images and borders on image containers: h5bp.com/e 
 */

img { border: 0; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; vertical-align: middle; }

/*
 * Correct overflow not hidden in IE9 
 */

svg:not(:root) { overflow: hidden; }


/* =============================================================================
   Figures
   ========================================================================== */

figure { margin: 0; }


/* =============================================================================
   Forms
   ========================================================================== */

form { margin: 0; }
fieldset { border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

/* Indicate that 'label' will shift focus to the associated form element */
label { cursor: pointer; }

/* 
 * 1. Correct color not inheriting in IE6/7/8/9 
 * 2. Correct alignment displayed oddly in IE6/7 
 */

legend { border: 0; *margin-left: -7px; padding: 0; }

/*
 * 1. Correct font-size not inheriting in all browsers
 * 2. Remove margins in FF3/4 S5 Chrome
 * 3. Define consistent vertical alignment display in all browsers
 */

button, input, select, textarea { font-size: 100%; margin: 0; vertical-align: baseline; *vertical-align: middle; }

/*
 * 1. Define line-height as normal to match FF3/4 (set using !important in the UA stylesheet)
 * 2. Correct inner spacing displayed oddly in IE6/7
 */

button, input { line-height: normal; *overflow: visible; }

/*
 * Reintroduce inner spacing in 'table' to avoid overlap and whitespace issues in IE6/7
 */

table button, table input { *overflow: auto; }

/*
 * 1. Display hand cursor for clickable form elements
 * 2. Allow styling of clickable form elements in iOS
 */

button, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] { cursor: pointer; -webkit-appearance: button; }

/*
 * Consistent box sizing and appearance
 */

input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] { box-sizing: border-box; }
input[type="search"] { -webkit-appearance: textfield; -moz-box-sizing: content-box; -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; box-sizing: content-box; }
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration { -webkit-appearance: none; }

/* 
 * Remove inner padding and border in FF3/4: h5bp.com/l 
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner, input::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; padding: 0; }

/* 
 * 1. Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE6/7/8/9 
 * 2. Allow only vertical resizing
 */

textarea { overflow: auto; vertical-align: top; resize: vertical; }

/* Colors for form validity */
input:valid, textarea:valid {  }
input:invalid, textarea:invalid { background-color: #f0dddd; }


/* =============================================================================
   Tables
   ========================================================================== */

table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
td { vertical-align: top; }


/* ==|== primary styles =====================================================
   Author: 
   ========================================================================== */

body {
    background:url(../img/background.png) repeat;
    font-size:100%;
}

/* =============================================================================
   header
   ========================================================================== */
#masthead {
    background: url(../img/header.gif) repeat-x;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    height:54px;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    z-index:1000;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=1, offy=1); 
}
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #logo {
        height:54px;
        line-height:50px;
    }
        #logo img {
            padding:0px 15px 0px 0;
            background: url(../img/header-sep.png) no-repeat right;

        }
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #tools {
     text-align:right;
    }
        #tools ul {
            float:right;
        }
            #tools ul li {
                display:inline;
            }
/* =============================================================================
   main
   ========================================================================== */

#main .dragbox{
    margin:20px 15px;
    padding:10px;
    width:207px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #4e4e4e;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000000; 
    float:left;
}
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #main .dragbox h2 {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        font-size: .8em;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background: #7b7b7b; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #515151 0%, #303030 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#515151), color-stop(100%,#303030)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #515151 0%,#303030 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #515151 0%,#303030 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #515151 0%,#303030 100%); /* IE10+ */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#515151', endColorstr='#303030',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        background: linear-gradient(top, #515151 0%,#303030 100%); /* W3C */
        padding: 0px 12px;
        cursor: move;
        font-family:'cabin';
        border-top: thin solid #777777;
        border-left: thin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
        border-right: thin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
        border-bottom:solid thin #1a1a1a;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #606060;
        color:#000000;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        line-height:2.4em;
    }
        #main .dragbox h2 a {
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#000000;
        }
            #main .dragbox h2 a:hover {
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
                color:#aadb02;
            }
                #main .dragbox h2 span.close {
                    float:right;
                }
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    .dragbox-content{
        background:#fff;
        min-height:100px;
        border-left: 1px solid #a3a3a3;
        border-right: 1px solid #a3a3a3;

    }
        .dragbox-content p {
            margin:0;
        }
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #main .dragbox-footer {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background: #7b7b7b; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7b7b7b 0%, #4d4d4d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7b7b7b), color-stop(100%,#4d4d4d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7b7b7b 0%,#4d4d4d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7b7b7b 0%,#4d4d4d 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7b7b7b 0%,#4d4d4d 100%); /* IE10+ */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7b7b7b', endColorstr='#4d4d4d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        background: linear-gradient(top, #7b7b7b 0%,#4d4d4d 100%); /* W3C */
        padding: 6px 12px;
        cursor: move;
        font-family:'cabin';
        border-bottom: thin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
        border-left: thin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
        border-right: thin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
        border-top:none;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
        color:#0c0c0c;
        font-weight:normal;
    }
        #main .dragbox-footer p {
            margin:0;
        }
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #ajaxLoadAni {
        background: #3A3A3A;
        color: #fff;
        display: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 40%;
        padding: 8px;
        width: 106px;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
        #ajaxLoadAni span {
            float: right;
            margin: 2px 0 0 0;
        }
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.ui-widget-content {
    font-size: .8em;
}
#delConfDialog, #msgDialog {
    font-size: 1em;
}



/* =============================================================================
   footer
   ========================================================================== */
footer {
    background:url(../img/footer.png) repeat-x;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:1000;
    height:75px;
    width:100%;

}
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #footer-top {
        height:50px;
    }
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #footer-bottom {
        height:24px;
        color:#999;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
        font-family:'Yellowtail';
        line-height:24px;
        color:#aadb02;
    }
        #copyright {
            float:left;
            line-height:30px;
            font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
            filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=0, offy=1);
            color:#212121;
        }
            #category-select form {
                float:right;
            }

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

input:focus, select:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.InputGroup {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
}

.ErrorField {
    border-color: #D00;
    color: #D00;
    background: #FFFFFE;
}

span.ValidationErrors {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #D00;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-style: italic;
}


/*  --------------------------------------------------
    Reveal Modals
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    .reveal-modal-bg { 
        position: fixed; 
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: #000;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        z-index: 100;
        display: none;
        top: 0;
        left: 0; 
        }

    .reveal-modal {
        visibility: hidden;
        top: 100px; 
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -300px;
        width: 520px;
        background: #eee url(../resource/img/modal-gloss.png) no-repeat -200px -80px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 101;
        padding: 30px 40px 34px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        -box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        }

    .reveal-modal.small         { width: 200px; margin-left: -140px;}
    .reveal-modal.medium        { width: 400px; margin-left: -240px;}
    .reveal-modal.large         { width: 600px; margin-left: -340px;}
    .reveal-modal.xlarge        { width: 800px; margin-left: -440px;}

    .reveal-modal .close-reveal-modal {
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: .5;
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        right: 11px;
        color: #aaa;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rbga(0,0,0,.6);
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
        } 

/* ==|== non-semantic helper classes ========================================
   Please define your styles before this section.
   ========================================================================== */

/* For image replacement */
.ir { display: block; border: 0; text-indent: -999em; overflow: hidden; background-color: transparent; background-repeat: no-repeat; text-align: left; direction: ltr; }
.ir br { display: none; }

/* Hide from both screenreaders and browsers: h5bp.com/u */
.hidden { display: none !important; visibility: hidden; }

/* Hide only visually, but have it available for screenreaders: h5bp.com/v */
.visuallyhidden { border: 0; clip: rect(0 0 0 0); height: 1px; margin: -1px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0; position: absolute; width: 1px; }

/* Extends the .visuallyhidden class to allow the element to be focusable when navigated to via the keyboard: h5bp.com/p */
.visuallyhidden.focusable:active, .visuallyhidden.focusable:focus { clip: auto; height: auto; margin: 0; overflow: visible; position: static; width: auto; }

/* Hide visually and from screenreaders, but maintain layout */
.invisible { visibility: hidden; }

/* Contain floats: h5bp.com/q */ 
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }



/* ==|== media queries ======================================================
   PLACEHOLDER Media Queries for Responsive Design.
   These override the primary ('mobile first') styles
   Modify as content requires.
   ========================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  /* Style adjustments for viewports 480px and over go here */

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Style adjustments for viewports 768px and over go here */

}



/* ==|== print styles =======================================================
   Print styles.
   Inlined to avoid required HTTP connection: h5bp.com/r
   ========================================================================== */

@media print {
  * { background: transparent !important; color: black !important; text-shadow: none !important; filter:none !important; -ms-filter: none !important; } /* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
  a, a:visited { text-decoration: underline; }
  a[href]:after { content: " (" attr(href) ")"; }
  abbr[title]:after { content: " (" attr(title) ")"; }
  .ir a:after, a[href^="javascript:"]:after, a[href^="#"]:after { content: ""; }  /* Don't show links for images, or javascript/internal links */
  pre, blockquote { border: 1px solid #999; page-break-inside: avoid; }
  thead { display: table-header-group; } /* h5bp.com/t */
  tr, img { page-break-inside: avoid; }
  img { max-width: 100% !important; }
  @page { margin: 0.5cm; }
  p, h2, h3 { orphans: 3; widows: 3; }
  h2, h3 { page-break-after: avoid; }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a link to a live version, or at least include the relevant HTML and CSS? Also, what version of Firefox are you testing this in?

Comment: Hi Chris, I have included the main html and css, I cannot post a link as the site is local.. I am using firefox 7.0.1, Cheers, Danny.

Comment: Man, when I asked for HTML and CSS, you definitely gave me plenty of it! I couldn't get the same problem to display, but it looks like the page's styles didn't get set correctly on my end. The first thing I would try is removing the `box-shadow` (and `-webkit-box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadow`) properties from the `footer` CSS selector. If that doesn't work, it might help to know if the CSS you posted is everything for the site, or just a portion of it.

Comment: Chris is just ahead of me! :-) It is a little hard to troubleshoot without a live site, without ff7, but I am guessing your header and footer shadow-thing:     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); as it is only on one side. There is a whole bunch of images there we cannot see, obviously.

Comment: Sorry Guys! Been majorly stacked out.. I think it is a bug as wordpress has the same problem with their front-end admin bar.. I noticed it two days ago whilst setting up a wp installation for a client.... I would love to post a link but I am trying to keep this little jem close-to-chest, hopefully it'll make life easier for some people.. It is my first php/jq app started without any knowlege of php.. I am cramming HARD!! :) Thank you for your time guys, I think I am just going to go with jQuery Waypoints to sort it out.. Take care, Danny.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a Firefox bug, when you are using `position:fixed` with `background-color:rgba()`, it cause that problem. You can fix it changing the `position` to other value, changing the `background-color` to a solid color or adding `-moz-border-radius:0 1px`.

Comment: Yup

-moz-border-radius:0 1px;
border-radius: 0 1px 0 1px;

Does the trick.

Thanks

Comment: @Bodman I am not recommending the use of general border-radius to 'fix' this problem because that will affect all the other standard browser like Chrome, Opera, while the problem presents only in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting strange border artifacts around a span with a PNG background and a border.

I "fixed" that by adding a white border on the parent. It probably still has those artifacts, it's just that it's not visible anymore.